# Problem with using pip instalation of python tools

Tags: python, openssl, pip

I have problem with using pip in unix. 
If I download a package, there is no prolbem to install it by :

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

But if I would like to install it by

```
pip install "package"
```

I receive error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   setuptools-scm (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for
>   setuptools-scm
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-19.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/*vendor/urllib3/util/ssl*.py:150:
>   InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
>   This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
>   certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of
>   Python to solve this. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>   InsecurePlatformWarning Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl
>   certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)) -
>   skipping

Do you know where could be a problem please?

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: did you try pip install setuptools_scm

Comment: Andrei:I tried sudo apt-get update

Comment: Yes, I tried pip install setuptools_scm and I received same error...Every package I tried to install by pip, I am receiving same error

Comment: I fixed a problem with : sudo apt-get install python-dev

Answer (score 0):

First, You try

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Then, try:

```
pip3 install "package"
```

Comment: I do not have installed python3 on server, but I received this error: Ignoring file 'fil.list.backup' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension. I think, there could be some problem with source.list maybe..